# Keyboard shortcut to exit browser address bar

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser

What's the inverse of `Ctrl+L` in a browser?

Say, you are typing the address but suddenly change your mind. Or maybe you forgot something on the current page and want to go back to it. How to do it, without using the mouse to click on the web page?

Comment: It might be good to edit your question and say which browser you are using.  If FF try Esc to exit or ^Z to backup.

Comment: I am looking for a universal shortcut that works everywhere. Esc does not work in FF.

Comment: I wrote [a blog post](https://transang.me/shortcut-to-leave-address-bar/) on how to accomplish this in any platform with chrome

Answer (score 12):

Try F6. It *toggles* between the address bar and the page for most browsers. If you're using Opera though, try Ctrl-L and Escape. ;-)

**EDIT:** In Chrome, hit F6 to toggle between the address bar, the bookmark bar, and then the page. If you've got the bookmark bar showing, hit F6 once to go from the page to the address bar, and twice to return to your last textbox in focus.

Comment: Nice, F6 works like this for Firefox, no luck in Chromium though.

Comment: Tried in Chrome -- no good.

Comment: In Chrome, F6 cycles between the location bar, open tabs, bookmarks in the bookmark bar (if visible), and the content area of the active tab. However, selecting the content area of the active tab doesn't seem to restore keyboard navigation: up, down, page up, page up, and space no longer work to scroll the content area. So F6 doesn't do what I really want it to do, which is simply undo Ctrl-L.

Comment: For *Firefox* `F6` works well `Ctlr` + `L` + `Esc` / `Alt` + `D` + `L` don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there are any shortcuts to jump back to where you were, it is rather a case of use a shortcut to take you where you want to go. Again, however, I don't think there is any shortcut to take you to the page body, but for me on Iceweasel (Firefox) a TAB takes me to the search bar and another takes me to the page body. Chromium just needs one tab. I doubt many browsers will be any more two.

So a short answer would be TAB once for Chrome and twice for Firefox.

Comment: This does not work -- you never know how many times you need to hit TAB, because it depends on pre-defined TAB order of a particular page. For example this particular page has elements that capture focus on TAB, and it takes 3 or 4 before you can, e.g. pgup/pgdn to move around the page.

Comment: Works fine for me. Two tabs in Iceweasel selects the page as a whole, same effect as F6. Chromium tabs through the links. All scrolling keys work fine regardless.

Comment: Could be that the effects of TAB vary with OS though - implementation of widget kits might be slightly different at this level.

Comment: Works in Firefox, but not in Chrome.